# Image Processing: Find the prominent page in an open Book and do a perspective transform

Tags: android, image, opencv, image-processing, edge-detection

I have to make this image [Book Image To Process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxivJ.jpg) having a page of a book with title: "Unit 3: The secret of Active Learning" to be the only page in the image

For this I need to remove part of the other page that Is also in the image

I need to write an Universal code that can do this for many similar images

I tried used Canny edge detection it is not able to detect the page as I want it to

If someone could please help guide me as to what I can use to achieve this i...it would be highly appreciated

Thanks in advance

[EDIT]

This is basically what I did using Canny edge detector

```
        Imgproc.Canny(gray,canny,0,50);
        Imgproc.findContours(canny, contours, hierarchy,
                Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
        for(int i=0;i<contours.size();i++){
            double temp=Imgproc.contourArea(contours.get(i));
            if(temp>100){
                if(temp>largestArea){
                    largestArea=temp;
                    largestAreaIndex=i;
                }
            }
        }
        m2f=new MatOfPoint2f(contours.get(largestAreaIndex).toArray());
        arc=Imgproc.arcLength(m2f,true);
        Imgproc.approxPolyDP(m2f,approx,0.02*arc,true);
        if(approx.toList().size()==4){
            Imgproc.drawContours(img,contours,largestAreaIndex,new Scalar(255,255,255));
        }
```

Comment: maybe you should start with getting some basics? also your question is way too broad. "I tried using Canny" also does not show too much effort from your side.

Comment: Hey @Piglet please check my edit. Thanks!

Comment: Please read [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Slice the image in vertical strips. In every strip, eliminate the top and bottom black areas. Then estimate the gray-value variance (or gradient modulus variance) in the strip or a similar activity indicator. This will reveal empty strips, which should be enough to grossly detect the right page.

---

A hint about the perspective transform: perform an erosion with a high structuring element so that the characters from successive rows come to merge. This will create strong edges giving you the vertical directions.

[image]